# Setting ratio of Young and Tenure generation in JVM for a String processing app

Tags: java, tomcat, jvm, jvm-arguments

I have an app which groups array of strings based on their similarity. It is exposed from a TomCat server and the start params are

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java/bin/java -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/home/username/shared/log/heapdump.log -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -XX:NewRatio=3 -Xms8192M -Xmx8192M -XX:+UseParNewGC -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -Xloggc:/home/username/shared/log/gc.log -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=7896 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -classpath :/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar:/usr/share/java/commons-daemon.jar -Dcatalina.base=/usr/share/tomcat7 -Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/tomcat7 -Djava.endorsed.dirs= -Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/cache/tomcat7/temp -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/share/tomcat7/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
```

My GC log goes something like

```
316.795: [GC 316.795: [ParNew: 233516K->15658K(249216K), 0.0143200 secs] 1899624K->1683370K(8360960K), 0.0143830 secs] [Times: user=0.17 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs]
```

I am constantly getting (concurrent mode failure) error in my GC log. I believe, it's because the size of Young Generation is very small. I am trying to set the ratio of Young Generation to New generation as 3:1, but as can be seen from the log, the size of young generation is still 249216K.

Why is JVM not respecting the `-XX:NewSize` option?

Answer (score 0):

check out this [guide](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html), specifically the

> The Young Generation

section:

> By default, the young generation size is controlled by NewRatio. For example, setting -XX:NewRatio=3 means that the ratio between the young and tenured generation is 1:3. In other words, the combined size of the eden and survivor spaces will be one fourth of the total heap size.

looks like you're setting the ratio in the way opposite than desired